# GitHub API? getting team info

Tags: github, github-api

i am having trouble on using the github api using GET.

according to **GitHub API**:
i should call:

```
https://api.github.com/teams/1
```

and i receive the ff json data:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

here is the link for the documentation:
https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#get-team

i cannot get the team info somehow.

Comment: Are you properly authenticated? https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Comment: @VonC i am but still, i couldn't possibly think to put my AUTH along with a GET method.

Comment: e.g. `https://api.github.com/teams/1?access_token=blahblah` - is this safe to add in a link?

Comment: It is safe in your own script. Here you wouldn't put your actual access token.

Answer (score 1):

If this depends on your being [correctly authenticated](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), then putting an oauth2 is fine, since such a key can:

- be [obtained programmatically](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization)
  (like in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tr3buchet/4482201))

  ```
  curl -u 'your_user_name' -d '{"scopes":["gist"],"note":"gister script test"}' https://api.github.com/authorizations
  ```
- be revoked.

Then this could work better:

```
https://api.github.com/teams/1?access_token=OAUTH-TOKEN
```